# Get all value from multiple form with same field name without formset

Tags: python, django

How to get all values from multiple form with same field name without formset?

there is my view.py file

```
...
test = str(request.POST.getlist('testing123[]'))
...
```

and there is html file

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="testing123[]">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button_rip btn btn-warning" title="Add field">+</a>
</div>
```

with js script to clone form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var maxField = 100; //Input fields increment limitation
      var addButton = $('.add_button_rip'); //Add button selector
      var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper_rip'); //Input field wrapper
      var fieldHTML = '<div class="spacer-divide"></div><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="test"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button_rip btn btn-warning" title="Add field">-</a></div>'; //New input field html 
      var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

      //Once add button is clicked
      $(addButton).click(function(){
          //Check maximum number of input fields
          if(x < maxField){ 
              x++; //Increment field counter
              $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
          }
      });

      //Once remove button is clicked
      $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button_rip', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html
          x--; //Decrement field counter
      });
  });
  </script>
```

i tried to print with this

```
print (test)
for x in range(len(test)):
  print (test[x],end=" ")
```

and the result just first value

im sorry my mistake i have wrong code at this line

```
var fieldHTML = '<div class="spacer-divide"></div><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="test"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button_rip btn btn-warning" title="Add field">-</a></div>';
```

it must be

```
var fieldHTML = '<div class="spacer-divide"></div><div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="testing123[]"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button_rip btn btn-warning" title="Add field">-</a></div>';
```

Comment: First of all if you want list of items, why you are trying to cast them as a str ?

Comment: because i need string output

Comment: Okay, but see my answer. Django's .getlist() method should return python's list. You can iterate over this list and then cast single item as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
test = request.POST.getlist('testing123[]')
print(test) # first check if test contains multiple elements and then start iteration over it
for t in  test:
    print(t) # you can cast it as a string now, print(str(t)). this return single element.
```

Comment: i dont know but when i print it just first value

Comment: This case give us information about QueryDict, print(request.POST) and give us information about testing123[] key. how it looks like ?